# How to watch controller asynchronous data in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I define a directive in angular 1.4，which receives a scope parameter “b”:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('m')
        .directive('mydirective', mydirective);

    /** @ngInject */
    function mydirective() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/mydirective/mydirective.html',
            scope: {
                b: '='
            },
            controller: MydirectiveController,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindToController: true
        };
        return directive;

    /** @ngInject */
    function MydirectiveController($scope, $state) {
        var vm = this;
        //here How to watch the parameter b to refresh the directive html result？
    }
```

in html page:

```
<mydirective b="ctrl.b"></myupl>
```

in the business controller， b is got from an angular resource

```
PayService.getBusinessNumber().then(function(results){
    vm.b = {business_id: results.no};
});
```

in index.route.js which define the route and the business controller，

```
$stateProvider
    .state('payShowInfo', {
        url: '/payShowInfo',
        templateUrl: 'app/pay_show_info.html',
        controller: 'PayShowController',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    });
```

my problem is , When the directive loaded, the parameter “b” is undefined,  How to watch controller asynchronous data in angular directive? and then use the new value of “b” to refresh the html page?

Comment: You already bind the `b` to your controller, so you can just do in your template: `<div>{{ ctrl.b }}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

If you define the directive parameter as "=", you mean that you will have two way data binding. So if you change the value in the controller, you will have the change reflected in the view.

```
angular.module('nib', [])
    .directive('mydirective', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                b: '='
            },
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

            },
            template: '<div>Test: {{b}}</div>'
        };
    })
    .controller('ctrl',function($scope){

      $scope.click = function(){ // emulating asynchronous request
        $scope.test = 'testing';
      }

    })
```

See in the plnkr below:

http://plnkr.co/3qs1NpU1aIhKzxyCMXjh?p=preview